# Annapurna Logo Effects Recreation

Tags: after-effects, motion-graphics

I'm looking to see how to recreate the effects used on the Annapurna Logo. I think it's awesome. Here's a reference:

In this they have scan lines and a glowing vertical reveal. The VHS tracking is interesting as well, but I'm really interested in understanding how to create the effects of the former to something like that.

Is this possible in after affects and what effects should I be looking into to achieve this? (Hope this is the right forum for this.)

Answer (score 1):

This is absolutely possible to create in After Effects. Without you asking a specific question it's difficult to give a specific answer here, but broadly speaking:

- **Scan Lines** in principal are very easy, they're just alternating black and white lines, set to a blending mode like `Overlay` and their opacity reduced
- A **Vertical Reveal** is most simply achieved using the `Linear Wipe` effect
- There are a lot of blurs and overexposures in this, which tells me you'd want to change your project settings to 32 Bit Color Space
- **Chromatic Abberation** is a key part of this look -- essentially you precompose your composition, duplicate it three times (red, green, and blue), and apply color channel effects and offset the position of each one.
- The **VHS footage** is almost certainly a recording of real static from a VHS tape, composited in using a blending  mode like `Add` or `Screen`

  This is a pretty popular look these days and as such there are all sorts of tutorials if you search for "Retro 80's VHS". [Here's a good example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Gh2n0-Zt9s).

If you have a more specific question please let me know.